# Open Quic (protocol) session via JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, quic

I have started messing around with the QUIC protocol and successful created a server-client session as explained here:
https://www.chromium.org/quic/playing-with-quic

Can I create a session from JS only? If I don't want to change anything on my website and only use QUIC for special data transfer (files ,images) so creating a session via JS and start pulling all the website images via udp (alot faster) and just inject them to the DOM.
Is this possible?