# QUIC communication between Chrome and server

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-3.x, google-chrome, quic

I have been looking into QUIC recently and have looked through different implementations, e.g. [aioquic](https://github.com/aiortc/aioquic) and QUIC for Node.js.

All the examples, which are given for these implementations seem to be aimed at server-to-server communication, or at least I couldn't find any example, which uses script, that could be used in a browser.

Are there any examples on how to create and open a QUIC connection from Javascript on the web browser (e.g. Chrome, since it is one of the few browsers, which "support" QUIC at the moment)?

What I want to try out in the end is file upload and download, but an example for a general request/response communication between the web browser and server using QUIC would already be a big help.

Related, but unanswered question: [Open Quic (protocol) session via JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47175034/9038475)

Comment: Isn't HTTP over QUIC the basis for HTTP/3 which is in Chrome, but not enabled by default?

Comment: Yes, HTTP over QUIC is now HTTP/3, if I understood it correctly. But I haven't found an example of how to use QUIC or HTTP/3 through JS in the web browser.

Comment: For the latest generation of QUIC, I think you will need a browser that supports HTTP/3 natively because Javascript in a browser does not have the ability to implement lower level protocols like HTTP over QUIC from pure Javascript.  Apparently, recent builds of Chrome can do HTTP/3 with a command line flag.  You can't even do UDP from browser Javascript.

Comment: FYI, the browser decides whether to use http, http/2 or http/3 through some auto-negotiation.  It's my understanding that it may even take a few connections to a site before it figures out it can use http/3.  Worth reading this: https://blog.cloudflare.com/http3-the-past-present-and-future/.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. I just thought, that it is also necessary to open the QUIC session in the web browser, since all the QUIC examples, which I have found so far used server and client to create a QUIC session.

Comment: Well, if you're using the browser, there's no specific QUIC flag or QUIC library to use QUIC.  You just use `fetch()` and if the target is known to support http/3, then the browser will use http/3 (which is based on QUIC).  From nodejs, you could use QUIC yourself independent of http/3 to a known host that supports it, but that's only in nodejs where you have many more networking options.